# MongoDB query execution time metric in prometheus

Tags: mongodb, prometheus, grafana, percona, exporter

I would like to know is there any metric in mongodb exporter which tells the amount of time taken to execute a query.

I am unable to find such a metric, I used this mongodb exporter https://github.com/percona/mongodb_exporter If any query exists please let me know. If its a counter or a gauge please let me know the statement that is to be written in prometheus query language to visualize that time taken on grafana.

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I have the exact same question